# Unable to resolve CRM web application url with hostname from outside browsers

Tags: networking, dynamics-crm

I have a deployment created with crm 2016 on-premise.

After installation. I am unable to use the webapplication URL from browsers outside the server.

If I use `FQDN NAME-IT IS GETTING RESOLVING` and able to access org.  Eg:

```
http://testserver.testserverdom.com/Englishorg
```

If I use hostname url-it is not resolving and getting blank page. Eg:

```
http://testserver/EnglishOrg
```

Again if I add host entry in `drivers/etc/hosts` file in  the outside machine like   `10.10.10.10 testserver`. Able to resolve and access URL.

I have added hostname(A) entry in DNS. I am still unable to resolve it with hostname.

Server have DHCP Assigned IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be having the DNS issue on client - side (outside of you server) which cannot correctly resolve your testserver.
If you run `cmd` and there try `nslookup testserver`- you should see if this is resolved with the correct ip address (according you your hosts file change this should be 10.10.10.10). If this does not -- I believe the problem is in DNS query / response, please make sure your local DNS server is configured correctly and make sure your local DNS server is sending back the response to your client.

Comment: able to resolve with fqdn name. but with shortname it is not resolving. with nslookup testserver getting correct ip address